# Disk quota exceed in openshift

Tags: linux, openshift, diskspace

I am using free openshift account and I suppose to have 1gb disk quota. And recently, I got disk quota exceeded error message

```
Warning: Gear 535142774382ec2f4f0004c6 is using 100.0% of disk quota
```

I run `du -h * | sort -rh | head -50` and here is the result.
I am quite sure that the sum of the usage is far below 1gb.

```
37M app-root/runtime/repo
37M app-root/runtime
37M app-root
35M app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo
35M app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862
35M app-deployments
30M app-root/runtime/repo/pma
30M app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma
12M git/api.git/objects/pack
12M git/api.git/objects
12M git/api.git
12M git
11M app-root/runtime/repo/pma/locale
11M app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/locale
7.5M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/libraries
7.5M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/libraries
4.7M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/js
4.7M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/js
3.8M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/doc
3.8M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/doc
3.4M    app-root/runtime/repo/js
3.4M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/js
2.6M    app-root/runtime/repo/js/lib/amcharts
2.6M    app-root/runtime/repo/js/lib
2.6M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/js/lib/amcharts
2.6M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/js/lib
2.3M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/libraries/tcpdf
2.3M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/libraries/tcpdf
2.2M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/themes
2.2M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/themes
2.0M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/doc/doctrees
2.0M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/doc/doctrees
1.8M    app-root/runtime/repo/js/lib/amcharts/amcharts
1.8M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/js/lib/amcharts/amcharts
1.7M    app-root/runtime/repo/chat
1.7M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/chat
1.5M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/doc/html
1.5M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/doc/html
1.4M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/js/jquery
1.4M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/js/jquery
1.3M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/themes/pmahomme
1.3M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/themes/pmahomme
1.2M    app-root/runtime/repo/pma/js/openlayers
1.2M    app-root/runtime/repo/js/lib/amcharts/amcharts/patterns
1.2M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/pma/js/openlayers
1.2M    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/js/lib/amcharts/amcharts/patterns
1.1M    app-root/runtime/repo/vendor
1004K   app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/paquettg
992K    app-root/runtime/repo/js/lib/amcharts/amcharts/patterns/chalk
992K    app-deployments/2014-07-19_11-50-18.862/repo/js/lib/amcharts/amcharts/patterns/chalk
```

But in phpmyadmin, it does show that my database use 500mb already. Why du does not show it? And what should I do to trim the disk storage?

```
Quota -s
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
                   105M       0   1024M            4023       0   80000
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get a look at your quota is by sshing into your app and running the following:

`quota -s`

Depending on your cartridge, the most common places that quota is consumed is in your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` (`~/app-root/data`) directory or in your application repo `~/app-root/runtime/repo`.

Either way the quickest way to clear up some space is with the `rhc app tidy` command.

Oh and your database is located in the `~/mysql` directory

Comment: It seems the mysql directory is not here
bash: cd: /var/lib/openshift/53513b82e0b8cdcc3b000001//mysql: No such file or directory

And I did try the tidy command, but it does not clean up much.